# Comparing current date/time with date/time in a database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to create something to display an image based on the current date and time.  I have an SQL table set up that looks like this:

```
eventid | startdate  | enddate    | imgfile    | status
6       | 2013-04-29 | 2013-05-03 | finals.jpg | active
```

What I need to do is compare the start date and end date to the current date, and if the current date falls within the startdate and enddate, then display the imgfile.

I'm not sure how to go about this, but this is what I tried.

```
//get current date and time
$currentdatetime = strtotime(now);
$formatteddatetime = date("y-m-d", $currentdatetime);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($getimage))
{
    //get variable for startdate
    $formattedstartdate = date("y-m-d", $row[startdate]);
    $formattedenddate = date("y-m-d", $row[enddate]);
    if($formatteddatetime >= $formattedstartdate AND $formatteddatetime <= $formattedenddate AND $row[status] == 'active')
    {
        echo $row[imgfile];
    }
}
?>
```

Right now, it doesn't show anything inside of the entire while statement.  Am I at least on the right track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it in your SQL query instead of PHP. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN startdate AND enddate;
```

`CURRENT_DATE()` is a MySQL function that returns the current date, as the name suggests. It is one of a few special functions that have an alias without the parentheses.

Comment: You are awesome, it worked!  Thanks so much.  I'm still just learning SQL so I had no idea that existed, haha.

Answer (score 3):

the CURRENT_DATE returns the current date in ‘YYYY-MM-DD’ format or YYYYMMDD format depending on whether numeric or string is used in the function. CURDATE() and CURRENT_DATE() are the synonym of CURRENT_DATE.